# Change CPT archive title

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, archives

I've created a custom post type named "documents" wich is working fine. By default, the CPT archive page title will also show "documents" as a title. I want to change that page title to "Library".

I tried the solution in

[Custom Post Type - Archive page title](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130747/custom-post-type-archive-page-title)

```
function new_cpt_archive_title($title){

if ( is_post_type_archive('myCPT') ){
    $title = 'My Custom post type archive - ' . get_bloginfo('name');
    return $title;
}

return $title;
} 

add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', 'new_cpt_archive_title', 9999 );
```

But it dates back 7 years and doesn't seeem to work anymore. Only the meta title is changed. Not the page title.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Can you be more specific what you mean by the page title? Are you refering to the `<title>` tags? A heading on the page?

Comment: <h1 class="entry-title">documents</h1>

Comment: can you insert the code that generates that heading into the question?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added the code in my question

Comment: I don't think that's the right code, that modifies the document title which is what's used by `wp_title`, but that filter does not appear in the question you used, neither does the `<h1 class="entry-title">`. It is not the code that is generating that h1 header. You will need to look again

Comment: You could just generate a different `archive.php` template just for your Documents CPT and apply Library as the title instead of letting it generate.